# Let a = ( x y z ) be an arbitrary vector of E. What are the coordinates of a in this basis B?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Where B = $$
    \begin{matrix}
    1 & 2 & 1 \\
    1 & 4 & 4 \\
    -2 & -1 & -4 \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$B$ represents the positions of the the basis vectors of E in the standard basis.
$B^{-1}$ would then be the positions of the standard basis vectors in terms of this basis.

$B^{-1}\mathbf v$ would be the image of an abritrary vector in this basis.